# How to split 300 months into groups of 60 for ggplot2 x-axis readability in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, split, axis

I have been searching for 2 or 3 days now trying to find a resolution for my problem without success. I apologize if this is really easy or is already out there, but I can't find it. I have 3 data frames that can vary in length from 1 to 300. It is only possible to display about 60 values along the ggplot x-axis without it becoming unreadable and I don't want to omit values, so I am trying to find a way to calculate how long each data frame is and split it into "x" plots of no more than 60 each.

So far I have tried: facet_grid, facet_wrap, transform and split. "Split" works ok for splitting the data, but it adds an "X1." "X2." ... "Xn." to the front of the variable names (where n is the number of partitions it broke the data into). So when I call ggplot2, it can't find my original variable names ("Cost" and "Month") because they look like X1.Cost X1.Month, X2.Cost etc...How do I fix this?

I'm open to any suggestions, especially if I can fix both issues (not hard coding into 60 rows at a time AND breaking into graphs with smaller x-axis ranges). Thanks in advance for your patience and help.

Stephanie (desperate grad student)

Here is some stub code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
xsz <- 60 # would like not to have to hardcode this
ix1 <- seq(1:102) # would like to break into 2 or 3 approx equal graphs #
fcost <- sample(0:200, 102)
f.df <- data.frame("Cost" = fcost, "Month" = ix1)
fn <- nrow(f.df)
fr  <- rep(1:ceiling(fn/xsz),each=xsz)[1:fn]
fd <- split(f.df,fr)
fc <- numeric(length(fd))
for (i in 1:length(fd)){
  print(ggplot(as.data.frame(fd[i]), aes(Month, Cost)) +
    geom_line(colour = "darkred", size = .5) +
    geom_point(colour = "red", size = 1) +
    labs(x = "Projected Future Costs (monthly)", y = "Dollars") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = .6))) 
}
```
````

When I run it, I get: 
  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Month' not found

When I do:
   names(as.data.frame(fd[1]))

I get:
   [1] "X1.Cost"  "X1.Month"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[[]]` for lists.

```
  print(ggplot(as.data.frame(fd[[i]]), aes(Month, Cost)) +
```

To answer your other question, you have to create a new variable with a plot number. Here I'm using `rep`.

```
f.df$plot_number <-rep(1:round(nrow(f.df)/60),each=60,len=nrow(f.df))
```

Then, you create a list of plots in a loop

```
plots <- list()  # new empty list
for (i in unique(f.df$plot_number)) {
 p = ggplot(f.df[f.df$plot_number==i,], aes(Month, Cost))   +
 geom_line(colour = "darkred", size = .5) +
 geom_point(colour = "red", size = 1) +
 labs(x = "Projected Future Costs (monthly)", y = "Dollars") +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = .6))
 plots[[paste0("p",i)]] <- p  # add each plot into plot list
}
```

With package `gridExtra`, you can then arrange your plots in a single one.

```
    library(gridExtra)
    do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots, ncol=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very VERY much! Works like a charm!